# US wire color coding clarification

Tags: cables, ul

I was buying a AC powered RV/Marine cord reel from outside USA. The cord has 2 lines, 1 neutral and 1 ground. The colors of the cores in the cord are red, yellow, blue and green. I need to use this cord reel in an electric charging station for vehicles in USA. Is it compulsory for us to US color codes for the wires ? 
Also, I was wondering if this could cause any issues with any certifications like UL, etc for the product in the future.

Comment: green=ground, blue=neutral. Keep those colours anywhere and you will hav no problems, they are standard and they must be used in that sequence.

Comment: Those colors look like the cable was intended as 3-phase/3-wire with earth/ground and no neutral. red/yellow/blue/green matches the European color codes and neutral would be black in that case. That being said, the electrons don't care about the color of the insulation and I don't know about listing agency or electrical code requirements in the US.

Comment: @brhans In EU we have green/yellow wire for earth, so no that cable isn't for EU, rather US, because it has green wire, which is used as earth in all US appliances.

Comment: you sure only 4 cables?  what AWG?  any markings on the cable?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I though that green was once acceptable as earth... In the US I don't think that red/yellow/blue is a standard combination though like it is in europe. black/red/blue or brown/orange/yellow are options.

Comment: @brhans, those are pre 1977 british 3phase colours (solid green, RED, YELLOW, BLUE) But it is missing BLACK for the neutral. As I stated in my comment 4wires is not enough for correct 3phase power, too many for single phase... I am wondering if it is component video ... equally as I said... what markings are on the cable

Comment: What markings are on the cable?  Pr,Pb,Y/V, VideoIn would satify 4wire and those colours.

Comment: @brhans Yep, they use white wire as neutral in US. Therefore the cable is for connecting induction motor 3 phase+earth without neatral. Green is earth, others are phases. The green always reamins as earth, now he has to choose which colour for neutral

Comment: @JonRB 4 wires are enough to conenct 3 phase power, it always was.

Answer (score 1):

In the USA, the National Electrical Code says:

- Ground must be green, bare or green/yellow (that last a concession to EU harmonization.)
- Gray or white are neutral.
- Hot wires can be any other color, including blue.

The UL certification process will probably hold you to those colors.  There's no conceivable reason to approve a color violation when cables of the correct colors are readily available from our robust and competitive domestic cable industry.

Now, you might be able to snake through a notched exception found in NEC 400.22c, which allows "light blue" for "jacketed cords furnished with appliances", *but only if there are no white or gray wires.*  I'm sure this is an EU harmonization thing, probably out of trade deals to avoid using wire colors as trade barriers.  I'm sure EU reciprocates, and allows white in the cord as neutral, if there are no blue wires in the bundle.

Hot colors aren't mandatory, but certain colors are common practice.

- Black = first phase (i.e. most common cables are green-white-black)
- Red = second phase (typically, 240 split-phase).
- Blue = third phase
- Brown-Orange-Yellow = alternate scheme for 3-phase, often to indicate a different voltage of 3-phase in a plant with several voltages.
- Blue-Yellow-Red = a rare alternate scheme for 3-phase, very common overseas
- Purple-Pink-Black = 3-phase power in Prince's house.

So -- Blue-Yellow-Red will suggest "a bit weird", and "3-phase delta".  That may not be the message you want to send.

P.S. 3-phase power without a neutral is called "delta".  It's a perfectly fine and normal kind of 3-phase power widely used in industry.